# How to retrieve grey value from a UIColor?

Tags: objective-c, image, colors, uiimage

If I have any random UIcolor and want to retrieve its Grey Value, how do I do this? I found this code on the apple site, but to me it doesn't make any sense as it only returns a bool.

```
- (BOOL)getWhite:(CGFloat *)white
       alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat grey, alpha ;
BOOL ok = [yourcolor getWhite:&grey alpha:&alpha];
if ( !ok ) {
    // handle error
}
// now use grey and alpha howsoever you want to like
grey = grey + 0.5;
alpha = alpha - 0.2;
```

//if you are making a new color

```
 UIColor * newColor = [ UIColor colorWithWhite:grey alpha:alpha] ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 questions: First, Why do you add 0.5 to the grey? 2)What is the range of values returned by this (what is black and what is white)?

Comment: i added 0.5 jsut to show you what you can do with the returned grey value. the returned values are grey and alpha and they range between 0.0 and 1.0